# Options in HTML <select> dropdown are too big in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-select, chromium

Some change in recent Chrome versions (likely in June 2017) cause options in a `<select>` input to render much bigger than in other browsers (or in older versions of Chrome).

For example, dropdown on [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select) on some machines renders like this (Chrome 60.0.3112.90, 64 bit, Windows 10):

[image: Chrome 60.0.3112.90, 64 bit, Windows 10]

instead of expected (Firefox 55.0, 64-bit, Windows 10):

[image: Firefox 55.0, 64-bit, Windows 10]

Is there any workaround that can be implemented in code to prevent it from happening (CSS solution preferred)?

So far I've found:

- [Discussion on Chrome product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/IO4USajnHOQ;context-place=forum/chrome), which confirms that this is observed by many people, but there's no answer whether it was intentional or not. Also, observations were made that presence of touchscreen drivers in a system might cause this behaviour.
- [Chromium bug #739196](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=739196&q=dropdown&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) describing this issue, but also with no clear answer whether it's intentional or a Chromium bug
- few answers suggesting that padding for `<option>`'s in a `<select>` can't be controlled via CSS by design, so this padding was never easy or possible to change.

Comment: Same problem here, also has a touch-enabled device. Looks like that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just add some CSS styling for the `<option>` tag to get it to look the way you want on most browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ahreu/50/

Comment: I can't attach a screenshot here, but this jsfiddle still renders differently (and noticeably bigger) in my Chrome

Comment: I have just updated Chrome to the same version as yours and the fiddle seems to be fine. In fact, I took the styling off and everything looks fine. Perhaps there is a plugin or something like that affecting your UI?

Comment: I also checked the fiddle (and the w3 page) with this specific Version of Chrome and it looks fine

Comment: @Sage, Matthias S.: thanks for checking. It seems that it's somehow related to hardware or software configuration then. It seem to occur on all machines in my company (all with similar setup), but good to know that not everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The additional padding was added in Chrome 59 for any device that Chrome thinks has a touch interface.  There currently is no way to disable this "feature".

[Chrome shows two rows in Dropdown-menu](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=739196&q=dropdown&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

[Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/IO4USajnHOQ/eVZ5dQ68AQAJ)

Answer (score 0):

Observed same issue on Windows 10 + Chrome, with no actual touchscreen interface.

Uninstalling/installing "Synaptics Pointing Device" (touch pad on laptop) fixed the issue for me. As the other forums mentioned, it appears to be related to Chrome thinking it is on a touch enabled device. Worth a try to disable/re-install devices that may appear as such.